# Bookdown demo returns error while compiling

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, bookdown

I'm trying to use the bookdown in RStudio IDE. So by click on new project, I have chosen the `Book Project using Bookdown` and named it `book_demo`. The project has all the files ready to compile. I made a connection to my git repo as well and then from the `Build` tab under Build Book, I have chosen the `Bookdown::gitbook` to compile the demo files but I have the following error :

```
output file: book_demo.knit.md

Error in dirname(input) : a character vector argument expected
Calls: <Anonymous> ... convert -> unlist -> lapply -> FUN -> file.path -> dirname
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Any idea why the default demo files are not compiling?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I re-installed the `Rmarkdown` package and it worked.